# The program 'rails' is currently not installed in the root of a Rails app folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I have a Rails app on a server and on a server only. It's not mine in the sense I'm not the one developed it. It's in Rails 2 and 3, in a Gemfile there's a condition whether it includes Rails 2 or 3 gem. I need to run some Rails operations on the servers such as `rails console, rails g migration`. However, when I run rails:

```
root@server123:/some_path# rails 
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
apt-get install rails
```

How can it be the case and how do I fix it?

```
# cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.4 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.4 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

UPDATE:

```
# bundle exec rails console
/web/my_app1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/web/my_app1/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rails-e86daf8ff727/railties/lib/rails_generator/generators/applications/app/app_generator.rb:7: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
      create  
      create  app/controllers
      create  app/helpers
      create  app/models
      create  app/views/layouts
      create  config/environments
      create  config/initializers
      create  config/locales
      //.... and so on
```

When I run the second time, it says "exists" instead of "create". What does it create? Why doesn't it run rails console?

Comment: It might be installed by bundler. Try `bundle exec rails`

Comment: restart terminal session or system may help

Comment: @Nithin, I restarted it, it didn't help. What about system?

Comment: That sounds like a rails 2 app -- "rails console" was new in rails 3, previously you did ruby script/console

Answer (score 0):

Try this command
`/bin/bash --login` in your terminal and then try using rails. I think it should work

Answer (score 0):

You are logged in on server as root(root@server123:/some_path).
It might be possible that rails is installed via deploy user.confirm that which user you use to deploy the code.ssh through that user and then try to run console.